# Foreground issue when using with Dynamic resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, foreground, dynamicresource

For my custom control, I am using the Dynamic resource to set the Foreground property. Initially when i run the app the Foreground property was not set to my control. When I change value dynamically Foreground was applied correctly. How can I resolve this issue?

PS: Simple sample [WpfApplication4](http://www75.zippyshare.com/v/76242743/file.html)

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="300"
    Height="200">
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="Red" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="Yellow" />

    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Create and Add Custom Control With Style" />
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick_1" Content="Change Color" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="myPanel" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = new MyControl {Style = this.Resources["MyStyle"] as Style};
        control.CreateContent(string.Format("My Control {0}", myPanel.Children.Count + 1));
        myPanel.Children.Add(control);
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var brush = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["ForegroundBrush"];
        Resources["ForegroundBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Add(brush.Color, Color.FromRgb(0, 100, 100)));

        var brush1 = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["BackgroundBrush"];
        Resources["BackgroundBrush"] = new SolidColorBrush(Color.Add(brush1.Color, Color.FromRgb(0, 100, 100)));
    }
}

public class MyControl : ContentControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);
    }

    public void CreateContent(string text)
    {
        this.Content = new TextBlock() {Text = text};
    }
}
```

Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4">
<Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You are not applying your `Style` anywhere except your `ButtonBase_OnClick` handler, so maybe *that* is why it is not applied until you click the `Button`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply a `Style` to a control, then you have to apply the `Style` to that control (which you haven't done in the code example that you have provided). You have two choices here... either try this (wherever you use the control):

```
<local:MyControl Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />
```

Or define your `Style` like this, which will affect *all* instances of your control within scope:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}" />
</Style>
```